# How to create tabs on the left in bootstrap.js v3.0.0?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create tabs on left using bootstrap.js v3.0.0  which is available in bootstrap 2.3.2.

But it is not showing tabs on left.

Please refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5QRky/) for more details.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
                doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
                veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim
                ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia
                cor magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro
                quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci
                velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore
                magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum
                exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea
                commodi consequatur?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <p>Section 2...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
            <p>Section ...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
            <p>Section ...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432577/stacked-tabs-in-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is fine, you just need some CSS (http://jsfiddle.net/5QRky/2/)

```
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li, .tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li {
    float: none;
}
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a, .tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a {
    min-width: 74px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 19px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a {
    margin-right: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover, .tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
    border-color: #eeeeee #dddddd #eeeeee #eeeeee;
}
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a, .tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover, .tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {
    border-color: #ddd transparent #ddd #ddd;
    *border-right-color: #ffffff;
}
```