# Jquery Tabs withing Bootstrap 3 not working

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use Vertical Tabs within my Bootstrap site. One I'm using are here :- http://bootply.com/74926

For some reason, I am unable to use them. They show perfectly but just doesn't become tabs. I guess for some reason, the tab functionality is being missed. Do I have to add some Tabs JQuery within Bootstrap 3?

The upper answer was provided in this link [Stacked Tabs in Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432577/stacked-tabs-in-bootstrap-3)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why don't you create a bootply link of your own, then it would be a lot easier to help.

Comment: I just created one. It is http://bootply.com/89407 ... The problem is, it works there (see those tabs); but it doesn't work on my local Bootstrap 3 site. I am sure I am not including some JS ... Please help :(

Comment: Yeah, you just need to make sure you're including (in order) jquery, and then either the main bootstrap.js or just the tab.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work tabs in bootstrap3 you should include **tab.js**

Comment: Thank you David. Did you mean this http://jqueryui.com/tabs/ ? As in, I should include `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>` ?

Comment: No,there is an tab.js in bootstrap3 dicrectory.

Comment: You can download the full minified bootstrap js, or just the components you want from: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/