# How to create a tab control in a web appliction using visual studio 2012 express for web?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing a website with visual studio 2012 express for web "asp.net" and I need to create tabs in the user profile>>>

I developed a desktop app before , there was a "tab control" I can drag it in the form

But I don't know how to add tabs here !!

Comment: I need your help guys <3 <3

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX toolkit is clunky and breaks most JQuery.  Beware of using it in a partial postback panel too.

Answer (score 0):

As far I remember the ajax control toolkit have a tab control out of the box, take a look to [this control](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_TabContainer.ashx) and see if that´s what you are looking for.

If you plan to have more control over the tabs you can use a [jquery UI control](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) but you will have more work to do.

You can create tabs using bootstrap as well, take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432577/stacked-tabs-in-bootstrap-3) and this is a [working example](http://bootply.com/74926) as well.

Everything depends on the requirements that you have and the functionality you want to put in place and which technology you feel more comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Here this should help you out.
Plus a whole load more controls..
[AJAX Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/getting-started/get-started-with-the-ajax-control-toolkit-cs)