# Vertical Tabs using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, tabs

How do you create a vertical tab navigation using Twitter Bootstrap , I am referring to a demo here
http://www.tutorialspark.com/twitterBootstrap/TwitterBootstrap_Tabs.php

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432577/stacked-tabs-in-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 0):

use .nav-stacked ([more info](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-tabs)) 
here's the working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/8940/)

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked col-xs-3">
...
</ul>
```

you'll need to add some css to fix the borders