# RStudio Shiny tabsetPanel position="right"

Tags: tabs, shiny, rstudio

I am using RStudio v0.99.473 and Shiny v0.13.0.  On my page I have a tabsetPanel within a fluidRow, with multiple tabs on it.  I am able to use the optional position="below" to move the position of the tabs from the top to the bottom of the fluidRow.  However, when I set the position to either "left" or "right", the tabs remain at the top of the page.  I have tried entering type="tabs" to ensure that it is not of type "pills", but this does not make any difference.  Can someone explain to me why this is not working.

The following code works:

```
tabsetPanel(position = "below",
  tabPanel("Plot), 
  tabPanel("Summary"), 
  tabPanel("Table")
)
```

This code does not, tabs remain at default position, above.

```
tabsetPanel(position = "right",
  tabPanel("Plot"), 
  tabPanel("Summary"), 
  tabPanel("Table")
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is unfortunate. Bootstrap 3 has removed the ability to position tabs anywhere but "above" (a lot of other people have [complained about this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8922)). See [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432577/stacked-tabs-in-bootstrap-3) for ideas of getting around this using css. Because of this, we're about to deprecate the `position` argument to `tabsetPanel()` in Shiny. Sorry :(