# Tabs right of the screen for Bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm looking for a Bootstrap3 component that adds tabs at the right of the screen and when you click a tab it opens. See this examples:

[image: tabs closed]

[image: tabs opened]

Answer (score 0):

If you see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432577/stacked-tabs-in-bootstrap-3), you'll see that these "stacked" tabs used to be in Bootstrap 2, but were removed in Bootstrap 3. You can get the same effect with additional CSS.

Example: http://bootply.com/74926

Comment: Thanks for comment. I already found this example, but it seems this doesn't slide out when click a tab.

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to add a CSS transition to get that effect