# Bootstrap Left Nav Tabs and Content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an HTML page using Bootstrap and with nav-tabs on the left as per the first answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432577/stacked-tabs-in-bootstrap-3) StackOverflow question. My codepen example is [here](http://codepen.io/mbacvanski/pen/grBVmr) where I attempt to have a table inside the second nav tab. However, how can I make the table be directly to the right of the tabs and not below all of them?

I've tried:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">

</script>

<body>
  <h3>Tabs left</h3>

  <!-- tabs left -->
  <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">Twee</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <th> H1 </th>
            <th> H2 </th>
            <th> H3 </th>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              ABC
            </td>
            <td>
              XYZ
            </td>
            <td>
              123
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              One
            </td>
            <td>
              Two
            </td>
            <td>
              Twee
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="b">Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis.</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="c">Thirdamuno, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add display:block in your .table class by default it is displaying it as display:table

```
.table{
  display:block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/palak6041/xz4mfvgk/2/

Comment: That puts the table on the same line, but how do I make the table the whole width of the screen?